# MySQL get_where with If condition in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following function in my model to filter officer records user wise. The function is working fine.

```
public function getOfficer()
    {
        $q = $this->db->order_by('last_name','ASC')->get_where('tbl_officer', array('status' => '1', 'usr' =>$this->session->userdata('id_user')));    
        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q->result();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Further, I want to filter officer records only for the user = 4 in the session, by p_code->8,10 and 24

The If functions as follows :

```
if($usr == 4)
        {
        $this->datatables->where('tbl_officer.p_code', 8)->or_where('tbl_officer.p_code', 10)->or_where('tbl_officer.p_code', 24);

        } else {
        $this->datatables->where('tbl_officer.usr', $usr);
    }
```

How can I include this If condition into my model function mentioned above ? What can be changed ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: I think you need to change your code if writing for active records try method chaining for this issue

Answer (score 0):

PLease use `where_in`

```
$this->datatables->where('tbl_officer.p_code', 8)->or_where('tbl_officer.p_code', 10)->or_where('tbl_officer.p_code', 24);
```

to

```
$this->datatables->where_in('tbl_officer.p_code', [8,10,24]);
```

Comment: @ kelvin kantaria. But I want to add it into my model function. Can you change my model using your suggestion ? including usr 4

Comment: @ kelvin kantaria. model code is included in the first section of my question. Named as getOfficer()

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change the method of query writing

```
public function getOfficer()
 {
     $usr = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
     $userArray = array(8,10,24);
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('tbl_officer');
     if($usr == 4){
        $this->db->where_in('usr',$userArray );
     }else{
        $this->db->where('usr',$usr);
     }
     $q = $this->db->get();
     if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->result();
     }
     return false;
}
```